Suggests to get flatpak updated without using the terminal? Ubuntu 24.04
These installations are meant for the average office user. I'm unsure if write a script to update periodically or have a software store to handle these tasks (even though the idea is unappealing since we'd need three different applications to manage .debs, snaps, and flatpaks).
For additional context, we also use snaps, but some applications aren't available in this package format (or are outdated) and must be installed as flatpaks.
Any suggestions from the experts around here?
Thanks.

The names of the apps may help as they may have ppa which means they might be updated on their own as needed.

You can get around with a single application to handle Snaps, Flatpak and debs: Gnome Software.

You might like to consider this answer to a similar question which will help with getting updates to Flatpaks without forcing them from the terminal.

It was not working greatfully in the past gnome-software, but maybe I should try it and delete snap-store. Thanks, @vanadium

Thanks for your reply @graham I'll get this in mind too.

@Noctis if you found that answer helpful, don't forget to upvote it as it could help others with similar concerns. Thanks.

What are you actually trying to achieve?  What are you asking?  Please provide more information on the apps and process you're trying to use?  It seems like you're asking how to make flatpak updates for ordinary office users, but your language is very unclear and ambiguous.  Otherwise your question will get closed.

At the moment, I installed in these machines with Ubuntu 24.04 the gnome-software. Seems more stable than I remember in a few versions and it can manage .debs + snaps + flatpaks. So I deleted the snap-store unfortunately.
